# When calculating the Gini coefficient for the US, how should the portion of the population which has not filed a return be incorporated?

Tags: econometrics, macroeconomics, gini

The [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) $G$ is a commonly used [measure of income distribution inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_inequality_metrics), taking values from 0 (meaning every individual in the population has an identical income) to 1 (meaning a single individual in the population earns the entirety of the population's income... and violent revolution is likely imminent ;). $G$ is the difference between the 'line of income equality' where income is distributed uniformly in the populace, and the [Lorenz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve), which describes cumulative income (or wealth, other social resources, etc.) as a function of cumulative portion of the population.

In the US, and in US states, $G$ is calculated using income tax return data provided by the IRS. For example, calculated from the IRS' [*Tax Year 2017: Historic Table 2* (*SOI Bulletin*)](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/17in54cm.xlsx). However, data based on US tax returns makes clear that the number of returns filed is (much) less than the population of the US.

This is to be expected, I suppose: we generally do not expect 2 year olds to be earning income, or filing taxes on it, for example. On the other hand, those not filing returns are probably a heterogeneous group, and likely include: the jobless (i.e. employable, but not working, not actively searching for employment, and not earning a taxable income… many full-time college students, for example), possibly some wealthy folks with income sources that are entirely (or nearly entirely) not taxable (e.g., they own a lot of treasury bills, or Muni bonds from their state of residence, etc.), and unemployable (e.g., the aforementioned toddler people persistently lacking language, etc.), possibly others.

**How are individuals *not* filing returns typically accounted for in calculating $\boldsymbol{G}$ as a measure of income distribution inequality? (Assuming that we have reliable estimates of the population size?)**

Are they:

1. Ignored? (I.e. is $G$ typically estimated as a measure of inequality *among those filing taxes*)?
2. Incorporated into the calculation of $G$ with zero assumed income?
3. Incorporated into the calculation of $G$ with some estimated mean outcome below the level required for filing taxes?
4. Incorporated into the calculation of $G$ with some other kind of estimated mean outcome?
5. Something else?

**Bonus question:** If there *is* some means of incorporating the whole population into the estimate of $G$, is this for all ages, or only for some range, such as 18–62 years?

PS One of the places where $G$ breaks down as a measure is when some people actually have negative incomes: certainly possible in the US today. It is probably Ok to leave this nuance out of the answer to this question… unless it isn't. :)